# htaccess file from server to localhost server configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php application which is hosted in a server. Everything is working fine there. Now My work is to make some changes in the css files. So I just downloaded all the files along with the database from the server to my localhost(LAMP). In my localhost I have set all the username and password for the database. Now when I browse the page it showed just a blank page. After that I just checked there is `.htaccess` file.Now this htaccess file is configurde as the live server environment. Now I don't have any good idea about htaccess configuration. So can someone kindly help me to solve the htaccess redirect issue
My `htaccess` code looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
php_value session.cookie_time 3600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
#php_value session.cookie_domain ".dummysite.com"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html $1.php
#RewriteRule 404\.shtml$ 404.php
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.dummysite\.com<>/([^/]*) 
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ - [E=USER:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dummysite\.com 
RewriteCond %{ENV:USER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) company_index.php?uid=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.dummysite\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*) company_index.php?uid=%1

RewriteRule categories\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html browsecats.php?browse=$1
RewriteRule categories\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html browsecats.php?browse=$1&cid=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&pg=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&cid=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&cid=$2&pg=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.htm$ $1.html
```

here dummy site is the website name. I have just replaced them. So can some one kindly tell me how to make setup this on my LAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy

1). go to LAMP -> apache -> apachemodules,
    Here turn on "rewrite_module" by checking it.

2). Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes shows blank page for a 500 error.
Active settings to display errors

In php.ini change error_reporting(E_ALL);

In the script ini_set('display_errors', '1');

To know where is the file, creates a script with the following content

//name  script
infophp.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```